# ForceBindIP not binding (Alternatives to ForceBindIP)

Tags: network-interface

I'm working on Win7 x64, and I can't get ForceBindIP to work. I know it's an outdated software, if you have suggestions for a replacement, I'll be really thankful.

Issue:
When I call ForceBindIP from command line, I get no error, the bound application starts and works normally, but on the default network interface, and not on the one I forced it to.

The real issue: (in case you can suggest something else)
On my work PC, we have a proxy to access the internet, which blocks lots of addresses (It's not managed by us, it's just a general list from Microsoft ForeFront...). We also have a wifi which is unrestricted, which I am trying to use to access an address which I use a lot. I'm trying to find a solution to bind an application to use the wifi, instead of the default network interface.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can edit the routing table, if the address is static.